# Unable to install gems ngrx/store

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have tried npm install @ngrx/store@1.2.1
but its failing with below reason 
npm ERR! unpack Could not read data for @ngrx/store@1.2.1
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-71-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "@ngrx/store@1.2.1"
npm ERR! node v4.2.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7

npm ERR! Invalid name: "@ngrx/store"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
i have done npm cache clean.
please help me out

Comment: Upgraded node and npm now it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Upgraded node and npm now it is working fine